# Get soundcloud Oauth2 token with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have successfully managed to authorise my ASP.NET application/login against a 3rd party service (in this case Soundcloud).  The API I want to use requires the authorisation token that was provided during the login process.  Where can I get the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in case anyone else wants to know, the token is available by using the Provider property in the options.  In this case, I set a claim with the token, which I can then access in the claims property of SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo()

```
app.UseSoundCloudAuthentication(new SoundCloudAuthenticationOptions
{
  ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
  ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET",
  Provider = new Owin.Security.Providers.SoundCloud.Provider.SoundCloudAuthenticationProvider
  {
      OnAuthenticated = async context =>
      {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessToken", context.AccessToken));
        await Task.Yield();
      }
    }
});


var accessToken = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "AccessToken").Value;
```